notify-send raising Thunderbird - with desktop-entry hint or -a app-name does not raise popup
Previously asked at https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?332611-notify-send-with-desktop-entry-hint-or-a-app-name-does-not-raise-popup with no responses.
Fedora 40, Gnome 46.
How should I make a notify-send popup raise Thunderbird when clicked?
I'm experimenting with notify-send and find that its -h flag with "desktop-entry" seems to cause it not to pop up at all. I can use a basic popup with no problems, for example:
$ notify-send "This is a test" "foo"

And hints work e.g. to get a sound to play:
$ notify-send "This is a test" "foo" -h STRING:sound-name:window-attention-active

I want the notify-send popup to consider itself associated with Thunderbird.
The documentation at https://specifications.freedesktop.o...t/ar01s08.html states:

"desktop-entry" STRING This specifies the name of the desktop filename representing the calling program. This should be the same as the prefix used for the application's .desktop file. An example would be "rhythmbox" from "rhythmbox.desktop". This can be used by the daemon to retrieve the correct icon for the application, for logging purposes, etc.

It doesn't say it will raise the program when clicked but it's worth a try. I have a desktop file for thunderbird at:
$ locate thunderbird.desktop
/usr/share/applications/mozilla-thunderbird.desktop
$ head /usr/share/applications/mozilla-thunderbird.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Thunderbird
GenericName=Email
Comment=Send and Receive Email
Exec=thunderbird %u
TryExec=thunderbird
Icon=thunderbird
Terminal=false
Type=Application

Great, so "mozilla-thunderbird" ought to be the string to use with the notify-send hint "desktop-entry". However this makes a sound but raises no popup:
$ notify-send "this is a test" "foobar2" -h STRING:sound-name:window-attention-active -h STRING:desktop-entry:mozilla-thunderbird

I have also tried:

with only the "desktop-entry" hint (i.e. removing the sound-name
hint, in case multiple hints cause problems)
with and without
Thunderbird running (checking ps to ensure the process isn't
running).
with -u critical to specify the urgency of the popup in
case Gnome decided it wasn't important enough to show (though if I
hear the sound hint I suspect the urgency bar has been passed and the
notification is attempting to act)

I also find that the -a command line switch acts unusually. From https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comment...ications_sent/ it can change the title, and indeed this makes the title of the notification a custom string:
$ notify-send "this is a test" "foobar2" -a "Funky program name"

But if I provide the desktop name of Thunderbird, no popup appears:
$ notify-send "this is a test" "foobar2" -a "mozilla-thunderbird"

So, -a appears to be doing some kind of work in response to the name provided, it's not a dumb string. I don't know if it's the same application lookup that the desktop-entry hint does.
Any clues please?
